# parsing and composing YAML

Tags: ruby, yaml, middleman

I have a basic question which I can't seem to sort out.

I would like to store a small set of Quote in a YAML file and then iterate thru it in a website using Ruby Middlemanapp.  I'm not sure if it's my YAML file composition or the way I'm trying to iterate thru it or both.

YAML (quotes.yml)

```
---
quote: "This is a quote"
attribution: "Kate Something"
extras: "Braintree"
---
quote: "Blah blah"
attribution: "Donna Doe"
extras: "Essex"
---
quote: "Blah blah"
attribution: "Donna Doe"
extras: "Essex"
```

ERB

```
<% data.quotes.each do |f| %>
  <%= f["quote"] %> #f.quote <%= f["attribution"] %> 
<% end %>
```

If I just use <%= f %> if get all items one after another regardless of the key but can find no way of iterating over them and specifying the key or field I want.

http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/local-data/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Yaml,, `---` starts a new document in a Yaml stream, so in your `quotes.yaml` you have three separate documents and you’re only reading the first one.

What I think you want is something like this:

```yaml
- quote: "This is a quote"
  attribution: "Kate Something"
  extras: "Braintree"

- quote: "Blah blah"
  attribution: "Donna Doe"
  extras: "Essex"

- quote: "Blah blah"
  attribution: "Donna Doe"
  extras: "Essex"
```

which is s single Yaml document containing a list of maps.

Comment: This solution seems to work correctly. A separate question -- what if 'extras:' has children? How would the ERB be written to iterate through children of the above YAML? Another question has been posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885392/accessing-multi-layered-yaml-and-middleman

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your YAML file format.

`---` is the marker for a document. `YAML.load` and `YAML.load_file` don't want to read multiple documents, only the first one, so you need to take a different track.

Try using `YAML.load_documents(File.read('quotes.yml'))` instead:

```
irb(main):005:0> asdf = YAML.load_documents(File.read('quotes.yml'))
[
    [0] {
              "quote" => "This is a quote",
        "attribution" => "Kate Something",
             "extras" => "Braintree"
    },
    [1] {
              "quote" => "Blah blah",
        "attribution" => "Donna Doe",
             "extras" => "Essex"
    },
    [2] {
              "quote" => "Blah blah",
        "attribution" => "Donna Doe",
             "extras" => "Essex"
    }
]
```

In other words, you'll receive an array of hashes for your particular data file. Each array element is a different document, parsed back into its Ruby object.